# Встраивание сообщения в proto

Tags: golang, google-protobuf

В protobuf `message` можно организовать встраивание, как это в структурах гошки сделано?

Например:

```
type MyStruct struct {
   A int
   B int
}

type MyStruct2 struct {
   MyStruct
   C int
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет, нельзя. Давайте посмотрим на [документацию](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/gotutorial)

> Don't go looking for facilities similar to class inheritance, though –
> protocol buffers don't do that

Вы можете рассмотреть один плохой прием, похожий на наследование

```
message Bar {
  int32 A = 1;
}
message Foo {
  int32 A = 1;
  int32 B = 2;
  int32 C = 2;
}
```

Эти два типа совместимы, потому что `Bar` является подмножеством `Foo`. Это означает, что если у тебя есть сообщение одного типа, то ты можешь декодировать его в другой тип. Если попытаешься декодировать `Bar` в `Foo`, то поля `B` и `C` будут нулевые(значение по умолчанию). Если попробуешь декодирвоать `Foo` в `Bar`, то поля будут игнорированы, точно также, как со временем добавляются новые поля в структуру.

Однако, минусов этого подхода тоже есть:

- при добавлении одного поля нужно добавить ее во все классы тоже.
- чтобы конвертирвоать один тип в другой нельзя просто взять и катсить, ты должен сериализовать их.